# Queries with Dynamic Parameters - better ways?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure that is quite extensive because of the dynamic @Name parameter and the sub query.

Is there a better more efficient way to do this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetClientNameList]
@Name varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    ClientID,
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name
    FROM
    Client
) a
where a.Name like '%' + @Name + '%'
```

Comment: This query cannot use indexes. Each way where you can use index have better performance - because of contentating string and your like expression beginning with '%' will never use index. The easiest way for this situation is use fulltext index and fulltext search. The best (but more complicated way) is decompose and normalize your input data.

Comment: Performance of a full scan with wildcards can be improved if you use a legacy SQL collation (`SQL[_]%`) or a binary collation (`%[_]BIN%`) instead of a Windows collation. The query will still be expensive due to the full scan.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the parameter Name ?  is it always the First or Last name ?  Can it be a partial name ?  Can it be a partial string of the combination of First+' '+Last ?  Because this select also opens new possibilities: First = 'Scott' Last='Tiger' - in your query name = 't T' will also find a match. Whereas comparing with each individually will change the result set.

Comment: A `like` query with a leading wildcard _can_ use an index scan if the query optimizer guesstimates that it will be more efficient than a table scan. The benefit is reading shorter rows, but not using the fact that the index has an order. Since your query applies `like` to a computed, but not persistent, column it doesn't matter. Aside: The `SP` prefix is best left to Microsoft and should not be used for user s'procs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamelessly stealing from two recent articles by Aaron Bertrand:

- [Follow-up #1 on leading wildcard seeks - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-performance/follow-up-1-leading-wildcard-seeks)
- [One way to get an index seek for a leading %wildcard - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-indexes/seek-leading-wildcard-sql-server)

The jist is to create something that we can use that resembles a [`trigram` (or `trigraph`) in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html).

Aaron Bertrand also includes a disclaimer as follows:

> "Before I start to show how my proposed solution would work, let me be absolutely clear that this solution should not be used in every single case where LIKE '%wildcard%' searches are slow. Because of the way we're going to "explode" the source data into fragments, it is likely limited in practicality to smaller strings, such as addresses or names, as opposed to larger strings, like product descriptions or session abstracts."

---

test setup: http://rextester.com/IIMT54026

Client table

```
create table dbo.Client (
    ClientId int not null primary key clustered
  , FirstName varchar(50) not null
  , LastName  varchar(50) not null
);
insert into dbo.Client  (ClientId, FirstName, LastName) values
  (1, 'James','')
, (2, 'Aaron','Bertrand')
go
```

Function used by Aaron Bertrand to explode string fragments (modified for input size):

```
create function dbo.CreateStringFragments(@input varchar(101))
returns table with schemabinding
as return 
  (
    with x(x) as (
      select 1 union all select x+1 from x where x < (len(@input))
    )
    select Fragment = substring(@input, x, len(@input)) from x
  );
go
```

Table to store fragments for `FirstName + ' ' + LastName`:

```
create table dbo.Client_NameFragments (
    ClientId  int          not null
  , Fragment  varchar(101) not null
  , constraint fk_ClientsNameFragments_Client 
      foreign key(ClientId) references dbo.Client
        on delete cascade
);

create clustered index s_cat on dbo.Client_NameFragments(Fragment, ClientId);
go
```

Loading the table with fragments:

```
insert into dbo.Client_NameFragments (ClientId, Fragment)
select c.ClientId, f.Fragment
  from dbo.Client as c
  cross apply dbo.CreateStringFragments(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as f;
go
```

Creating trigger to maintain fragments:

```
create trigger dbo.Client_MaintainFragments
on dbo.Client
for insert, update as
begin
  set nocount on;

  delete f from dbo.Client_NameFragments as f
    inner join deleted as d 
    on f.ClientId = d.ClientId;

  insert dbo.Client_NameFragments(ClientId, Fragment)
    select i.ClientId, fn.Fragment
    from inserted as i 
    cross apply dbo.CreateStringFragments(i.FirstName + ' ' + i.LastName) as fn;
end
go
```

Quick trigger tests:

```
/* trigger tests --*/
insert into dbo.Client (ClientId, FirstName, LastName) values 
(3, 'Sql', 'Zim')
update dbo.Client set LastName = 'unknown' where LastName = '';
delete dbo.Client where ClientId = 3;
--select * from dbo.Client_NameFragments order by ClientId, len(Fragment) desc
/* -- */
go
```

New Procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[Client_getNameList] @Name varchar(100) as
begin
set nocount on;
    select 
        ClientId
      , Name = FirstName + ' ' + LastName
    from Client c
    where exists (
      select 1 
      from dbo.Client_NameFragments f
      where f.ClientId = c.ClientId
        and f.Fragment like @Name+'%'
      )
end
go
exec [dbo].[Client_getNameList] @Name = 'On Bert'
```

returns:

```
+----------+----------------+
| ClientId |      Name      |
+----------+----------------+
|        2 | Aaron Bertrand |
+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for that. A very interesting read and solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess search operation on Concatenated column wont take Indexes sometimes. I got situation like above and I replaced the Concatenated search with `OR` which gave me better performance most of the times.

Create Non Clustered Indexes on `FirstName` and `LastName` if not present.

Check the performance after modifying the above Procedure like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetClientNameList]
@Name varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT 
    ClientID,
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name
    FROM
    Client
    WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' 
    OR LastName  LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' 
END
```

And do check execution plans to verify those Indexes are used or not.

Comment: Thanks Shakeer. Still an Index Scan however.

Comment: Is doing the above change made any performance difference? @James

Comment: This is not equivalent to the query in the question. What if the `@name` parameter contains `keer Mir`? The query in the question will find your name, but your query will not.

Comment: This qry is wrong. Have worse performance than request. This qry never use index too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem really comes down to having to compute the column (concat the first name and last name), that pretty much forces sql server into doing a full scan of the table to determine what is a match and what isn't.  If you're not allowed to add indexes or alter the table, you'll have to change the query around (supply firstName and lastName separately).  If you are, you could add a computed column and index that:

```
Create Table client (

  ClientId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
  ,FirstName VARCHAR(100)
  ,LastName VARCHAR(100)
  ,FullName AS FirstName + ' ' + LastName
 )

Create index FullName ON Client(FullName)
```

This will at least speed your query up by doing index seeks instead of full table scans.  Is it worth it?  It's difficult to say without looking at how much data there is, etc.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, even with this though it is still a scan.

Comment: This table can be scanned or can use idnex. Problem is in your qry and like expression beggining with '%' which cannot use index -> you force table scan with your like.

Answer (score 0):

```
where a.Name like '%' + @Name + '%'
```

This statement never can use index. In this situation it's beter to use **Full Text Search**

if you can restrict your `like` to

```
where a.Name like @Name + '%'
```

it will use index automaticaly. Moreover you can use `REVERSE()` function to index statement like :

```
where a.Name like '%' + @Name
```